# How does Kalman filtering of beta in pairs trading model work in R?

Tags: beta, pairs-trading

Could anyone show how this could be done in R? The `dlm` package seems to be a good start, but I can't really find any good examples to learn from.

Currently I have two timeseries of the closing prices for two stocks. I then do a rolling regression that gives me the corresponding timeseries of the beta between the two stocks.

How would I go about to implement a Kalman filter for this beta?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you checked out the vingette for [DLM](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dlm/vignettes/dlm.pdf) by Petris?

Incidentally, Petris also has an [R-book on the DLM package](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387772375) which includes estimation of beta as an example.

Comment: That's seems to be a nice book to reference. I found these two pdfs explaining kalman filtering too: [first](http://calypso.inesc-id.pt/FCUL/psm/docs/kalman-dan-simon.pdf), [second](http://wiki.nolanhergert.com/lib/exe/fetch.php?media=signals:poor_mans_explanation_of_kalman_filtering.pdf)

Comment: If you want to learn Kalman filtering in general I think a good text is Rene Carmona's Statistical Analysis of Financial Data: http://www.amazon.com/Statistical-Analysis-Financial-Data-S-PLUS/dp/0387202862/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1320976081&sr=8-1